# Find the probability for having real roots with the polynomial $x^2+ax+b$

Tags: probability-distributions

Choose two real numbers $a$ and $b$ satisfying $1<a<3$ and $-1<b<1$ randomly.

Find the probability that the polynomial $x^2+ax+b$ has two real roots.

NB: uniform distribution

Comment: What have you got so far? When does $x^2 + ax + b = 0$ have two real solutions?

Comment: So, if you know the distributions of $a$ and $b$, what would you say is the probability
$$
P(a^2 - 4b > 0)
$$ ? I would consider starting by making an auxiliary variable $z=a^2 - 4b$ and then consider its CDF.

Comment: I am French-speaking and it may be that my English is not well understood.
Otherwise talking about uniform distribution is well in the domain of probability in my opinion.(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\left[x^{2}>4y\right]$ denote the function with arguments $x,y$
that takes value $1$ if $x^{2}>4y$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Then:

$$\begin{aligned}P\left(a^{2}>4b\right) & =\mathbb{E}\left[a^{2}>4b\right]\\
 & =\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{3}\int_{-1}^{1}\left[x^{2}>4y\right]dydx\\
 & =\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{3}\int_{-1}^{\min\left(\frac{1}{4}x^{2},1\right)}dydx\\
 & =\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{3}\min\left(\frac{1}{4}x^{2},1\right)+1dx\\
 & =\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}x^{2}+1\right)dx+\frac{1}{4}\int_{2}^{3}2dx\\
 & =\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{1}{12}x^{3}+x\right]_{1}^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\\
 & =\frac{19}{48}+\frac{24}{48}=\frac{43}{48}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank sir , this is well the result i got by simulation by Monte Carlo method's.

Comment: What do you think Sir, about  the method which consists by passing through the surface generated by the discriminant in 3d-space and taking the ratio of the area corresponding to the positive values of the discriminant over the total area?
Is it more consistent than the method using a flat surface?

Comment: I think that no method exists that can be labeled as "more consistent than the method used in this answer".

Comment: Ok thinks very much.
I forgot the say that by that method, i got a result near 0.9 and here 43/48~=0.89583.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the distribution is uniform, you just need to compute the ratio between the shadowed area in the picture and the area of the rectangle.[image]

Looking at $a,b$ as random variables, you just have that
\begin{align*}
P(a^2-4c>0)=& \frac{1}{6} \left(3+ \int_1^3 \frac 14 a^2 da \right)=\frac{43}{48}
\end{align*}

Comment: Why does this method work? I'd be happy to expand my knowledge!

Comment: @uiyaba The $(a,b)$ points falling in the shadowed area are the ones that work. In continuous distributions, the count is substituted by the integral (area). The ration I propose is just the "number" of favorable situations divided by the total "number" of possibilities.

Comment: This curve conforms well to my simulation results by the Monte Carlo method.
Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: @uriyaba, you want $P(a^2>4b) = \iint_{x^2>4y}f_{a,b}(x,y)\,dxdy$, and assuming $a$ and $b$ are independent, this is equal to $\iint_{x^2>4y}f_{a}(x)f_b(y)\,dxdy$ and since $a$ and $b$ are uniform, this is just a ratio of area of $x^2>4y$ inside a square and the area of the whole square.

Comment: @Diakolo Belya, you mean, your Monte Carlo simulation conforms well to the curve.

Comment: Yes Sir .
How can i post an image, can you please explain the procedure!
Just to show the codes and the result of the Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: @Diakolo Belya, I would start by looking at the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=images). Follow the link there and go to the bottom.